# What is the difference between find(), findOrFail(), first(), firstOrFail(), get(), list(), toArray()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

What is the difference between these methods:

1. `find()`
2. `findOrFail()`
3. `first()`
4. `firstOrFail()`
5. `get()`
6. `list()`
7. `toArray()`

I've been using them and each one gives a different result and sometimes I need to add `toArray()` at the end of `get()` because my function is expecting an array. Won't the other methods produce arrays as well?

Comment: Have a look at the [Query Builder docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#retrieving-results), as well as the [Eloquent API reference](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html).

Comment: All information from @Joseph Silber is correct and very useful. I want to add an answer to list() From Laravel 5.2 The list method on the Collection, query builder and Eloquent query builder objects have been renamed to pluck. The method signature remains the same.

Answer (score 412, accepted):

1. **`find($id)`** takes an id and returns a single model. If no matching model exist, it returns `null`.
2. **`findOrFail($id)`** takes an id and returns a single model. If no matching model exist, it throws an error<sup>1</sup>.
3. **`first()`** returns the first record found in the database. If no matching model exist, it returns `null`.
4. **`firstOrFail()`** returns the first record found in the database. If no matching model exist, it throws an error<sup>1</sup>.
5. **`get()`** returns a collection of models matching the query.
6. **`pluck($column)`** returns a collection of just the values in the given column. In previous versions of Laravel this method was called `lists`.
7. **`toArray()`** converts the model/collection into a simple PHP array.

---

**Note:** [a collection](http://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-collections) is a beefed up array. It functions similarly to an array, but has a lot of added functionality, as you can see in [the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#available-methods).

Unfortunately, PHP doesn't let you use a collection object everywhere you can use an array. For example, using a collection in a `foreach` loop is ok, put passing it to `array_map` is not. Similarly, if you type-hint an argument as `array`, PHP won't let you pass it a collection. Starting in PHP 7.1, there is the [`iterable` typehint](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.iterable.php), which can be used to accept both arrays and collections.

If you ever want to get a plain array from a collection, call its [`all()`](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-all) method.

---

<sup>1</sup> The error thrown by the `findOrFail` and `firstOrFail` methods is a [`ModelNotFoundException`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/ec8fb5596b67de0edfcc8cc7c2167d6c184f080b/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/ModelNotFoundException.php). If you don't catch this exception yourself, [Laravel will respond with a 404](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/ec8fb5596b67de0edfcc8cc7c2167d6c184f080b/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php#L199-L200), which is what you want most of the time.

Comment: Thank you for the clear up. Here's the thing, I am trying to get a list of posts like this `$post = Post::with('user.votes')->with('subreddit.moderators')->findOrFail($post->id);` so I can access `$post->subreddit->moderators->user_id` but that is giving `Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$user_id` - I can access `$post->subreddit->moderators` but not when I added `user_id` - why is that?

Comment: `subreddit` is a single model, with a `moderators` property. `moderators` is a collection, not a single model. You can't access anything directly off of it. You can check the first one if you want: `$post->subreddit->moderators[0]->user_id`

Comment: I think you should replace "it throws an error" with "it throws an ModelNotFoundException exception" :D Anyway great contribution ;)

Comment: @JosephSilber Perfect!

Comment: You mean "instance", not "model". A model is a conceptual structure, or an example, not an actual instance. Let's be clear in our terminology. Sadly in the Eloquent world people are using the two terms interchangeably. An instance is not a model. An instance is a real implementation (object version) of a model.

Comment: @GeneC - The [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#not-found-exceptions) calls instances models: "throw an exception if a model is not found"

Comment: @JosephSilber the documentation is wrong. Consistent, but wrong. A model is is an idealized concept or example, not an actual instance of the thing it represents. In Laravel we have Model classes, which you can use to instantiate new instances (records, objects). You don't instantiate a new "model".

Answer (score 6):

Probably things changed but the findorFail method can take 2 arguments: `$id` and `$columns` mixed/array params respectively. Passing a second arg is not required. That said, this would work:

```
$post = Post::findOrFail([1,2], ['title', 'subtitle']);
```

If one of the `$ids` fails, the `ModelNotFoundException` with message 'No query results for model ... ' will be thrown.