# Get parents data in eloquent relation

Tags: laravel, lumen, eloquent

I have table like this:

Master_Table

```
    id      titile      desc
    1       one         one is one
    2       two         two is two
```

Child_Table

```
    id      value       master_id
    1       first       1
    2       second      1
    3       third       1
    4       fourth      1
```

So when I successfully retrieve the data, it would be a json like this:

```
    Master_Table {
        id:1,
        title:'one',
        desc: 'one is one',
        Child_Table: [
            {id: 1, value:"first", master_id:1},
            {id: 2, value:"second", master_id:1},
            {id: 3, value:"third", master_id:1},
            {id: 4, value:"fourth", master_id:1},
        ]
    }
```

I am doing it like this:

```
    $json= PDH::find(1)->products()->where('product_highlight_id', 1)->get();
```

But the result is only the child

```
        Child_Table: [
            {id: 1, value:"first", master_id:1},
            {id: 2, value:"second", master_id:1},
            {id: 3, value:"third", master_id:1},
            {id: 4, value:"fourth", master_id:1},
        ]
```

I am sure that this is available in Laravel Eloquent, but I hardly find it. Can anybody pointed it out to me, please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`with()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) method:

```
$pdh = PDH::with('products')->where('product_highlight_id', 1)->find(1);
```

Then `$pdh` will contain the parent object and `$pdh->products` will be a collection of products.

Comment: Very good! I just need to change the where clause. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to check `product_highlight_id` again as you have already check to get the `master object` and you are having corresponding `child collection`.

```
$json = PDH::with('products')->where('id', 1)->first();
```

I assume that **PDH** your master model.

Comment: What is the different between `first` and `find`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33027047/what-is-the-difference-between-find-findorfail-first-firstorfail have a look here