# Laravel trying to get property 'project_name' of non-object

Tags: php, laravel

I'm pretty new to Laravel, just to point things out. I have a problem with reading out my show page, the when I open the showpage (show.blade.php) it returns this error

> Trying to get property 'project_name' of non-object (View: C:\Server\data\htdocs\ProjectCMS\resources\views\project\show.blade.php).

I have no clue what I did wrong, because I got it working and as soon as I opened the showpage again it returned the error.

any help would be appreciated!

**ProjectController.php:**

```
public function show($id)
{
    $user_id = auth()->user()->id;
    $project = Project::where('user_id', $user_id)->first();
    $projectitem = Projectitem::where('project_id', $id)->first();

    return view('project.show', [
        'project'     => $project,
        'projectitem' => $projectitem,
    ]);
}
```

**web.php route**

```
Route::get('/projects/{id}', 'ProjectController@show');
```

**show.blade.php:**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

    <div class="container">

        <div class="well">

            <div class="card mt-5 mb-5">
                <h2 class="card-header">{{$projectitem->project_name}}</h2>
                <div class="card-body">


                    <h2 class="card-text mt-4 mb-2"><b>Beschrijving:</b></h2><br>
                    {!!$projectitem->description!!}

                    <h2 class="mt-4 mb-2"><b>Tijdsduur(in uren):</b>&nbsp;{{$projectitem->time_span}} Uren</h2><br>

                    <h2 class="mt-2 mb-2"><b>Opdrachtgever:</b> &nbsp;{{$projectitem->client}}</h2>

                    <h2 class="mt-4 mb-2"><b>Text verslag:</b></h2><br>
                    {!!$projectitem->text_report!!}

                    <h2 class="mt-4 mb-2"><b>Foto's vooraf: &nbsp;</b></h2><br>
                    {!!$projectitem->images_before!!}
                    <h2 class="mt-4 mb-2"><b>Foto's achteraf: &nbsp;</b></h2><br>
                    {!!$projectitem->images_after!!}

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <h2 class="mt-4"><b>Beschikbaar op: &nbsp;</b></h2>
                            <h4>Facebook:&nbsp;<?php if($projectitem->facebook == 1){echo "wel";}else{echo "niet";}?></h4>
                            <h4>Instagram:&nbsp;<?php if($projectitem->instagram == 1){echo "wel";}else{echo "niet";}?></h4>
                            <h4>Linkedin:&nbsp;<?php if($projectitem->linkedin == 1){echo "wel";}else{echo "niet";}?></h4>
                            <h4>Website:&nbsp;<?php if($projectitem->website == 1){echo "wel";}else{echo "niet";}?></h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <h4 class="mt-4 mb-2"><b>Aangemaakt door:</b>&nbsp;{{$projectitem->created_by}}</h4><br>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <h4 class="mt-4 mb-2 floatl "><b>Aangemaakt op:</b>&nbsp;{{$projectitem->created_at}}</h4><br>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <h4 class="mt-4 mb-2 ml-1 mr-1 floatr "><b>Laatst gewijzigd op:</b>&nbsp;{{$projectitem->updated_at}}</h4><br>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


@endsection
```

**Projectitem.php (model)**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Projectitem extends Model
{
    protected $table = "project_item";

    function project(){

        return $this->belongsTo('App\Project');

    }
}
```

**Project.php (model)**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Project extends Model
{
    protected $table = "project";



public function projectitem()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Projectitem');
    }

}
```

**migration projectitem table**

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('project_item', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('project_name');
        $table->string('client');
        $table->text('description');
        $table->float('time_span');
        $table->text('text_report');
        $table->text('images_before');
        $table->text('images_after');
        $table->boolean('facebook');
        $table->boolean('instagram');
        $table->boolean('linkedin');
        $table->boolean('website');
        $table->integer('belongs_to');
        $table->string('created_by');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Comment: on show function can you die dump dd($project) and paste the result here, also do the same for dd($projectitem)

Comment: the result is too big to post

Comment: can you see project_name?

Comment: $project is the object with only a id and user_id and $projectitem contains all the other data such as the name and description etc.

Comment: $project returns the whole object and $projectitem returns null

Comment: please check if $projectitem is not null

Comment: Can you share your model structure? It seems your `ProjectItem` model does not have the column `project_name`

Comment: i will edit it into my post

Comment: Cheers mate! Can you also provide the `migration` for that specific model? :)
You can find them under `database/migrations`

Comment: It seems your migration for that model does not contain a `project_id` field. That could cause the problem to find it and return null. You can double check this by using `dd()` in your `projectItem` object

Comment: yes it definitly returned null

Comment: If you are creating a relationship you will need to mention that at your migration as well, unless you have `ManyToMany` which will then generate a 3rd table to link both `projects` and `project_items` tables

Comment: I will provide a solution for your migration to sort it out :)

Comment: i already got a relation in my database, the problem is that it is not reading it out and its onetomany not manytomany

Comment: too bad i cant open a chat cause im not rep 20 yet

Comment: Right, so the way I see it you have 2 options. If you believe you will be havings IDs that possibily will not exist, then either you make an `Hydrator` to present empty data based if received an object or a null (making sure you always list). Or you check in your view to see if you received an object. If you did, execute what you have, if not, just output saying `No project was found`? If you wish to not direct to the view at all, you can add that logic to the controller (well better would be a service instead directly on the controller) and just redirect to a view that says Project not found

Answer (score 1):

Check that you have a record in your database for the `Projectitem` model.

It sounds like it is returning null which means no results are found for the where condition you have specified.

Answer (score 0):

In your blade use code like this:

```
$projectitem[' project_name'];
```

If it gives error related to `undefined index`, put the index before value like

```
 $projectitem[0][' project_name'];
```

Comment: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$'  is what it returned after replacing that line

Comment: Why is there a space in `[' project_name']`

Comment: there should be like 
projectitem['project_name'];

Answer (score 0):

**What is this**

Trying to get property of non object means - You are using `ProjectItem` models data, and that data is not present !!

**Solution**

You can do a better check by `findOrFail()` or firstOrFail().
Like this -

```
$project = Project::where('user_id', $user_id)->firstOrFail();
$projectitem = Projectitem::where('project_id', $id)->firstOrFail();
```

Read More about these -> [What is the difference between find(), findOrFail(), first(), firstOrFail(), get(), list(), toArray()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33027047/what-is-the-difference-between-find-findorfail-first-firstorfail-get)

Comment: thanks for the effort, but it returns a 404 page, when i did DD($projecitem); it returned null. so im pretty sure it doesnt get the object.

Comment: you can check also, if(!is_null($project)){ // View }else{// Do something}