# Laravel retreive data from database order by creation date

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to retrieve data orderby creation date desc and get the first one here is my code

```
$localnews = Articles::whereHas('sous_categories',
    function ($query) {
        $query->where('id', '15')->order_by('created_at', 'desc');
    })->get()->first();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have got error when using `order_by` as its not the syntax in Laravel.

```
$localnews = Articles::whereHas('sous_categories',
    function ($query) {
        $query->where('id', '15')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
    })->first();
```

Please have a look at [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset) to help you with.

And when using `first()` you don't need to use `get()`.

`get()` we use to fetch multidimensional associative array.
`first()` we use to fetch one record which matches first.

Here is concise difference between all functions you will use then after. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33027047/what-is-the-difference-between-find-findorfail-first-firstorfail-get).

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this,

```
$localnews=Articles::whereHas('sous_categories', function($query) {
    $query->where('id', '15')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
      })->firstOrFail();
```

Comment: yes that's mistake either first or get thanks for correcting me @kerbholz