# Laravel Find and first not working together properly

Tags: php, laravel, view, controller

In my function show in my employeeController is displaying the wrong id details of the view. What can be the be ideal solution other than using first()?

If I am just going to use the

```
$employee = Employee::find($id);
```

it will work but it will not display "company" details

but if I used the

```
$employee = Employee::find($id)->with('company')->first();
```

it will retrieve the first id and will not make use of the `find($id)`

I expect to output the id 9 but it keptgiving me the id 8 because of the `first()` in my controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `with()` static method, please refer to [doc](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_with)

For example:

```
$employee = Employee::with('company')->find($id);
```

Or you can find the record and load the relations

```
$employee = Employee::findOrFail($id)->load('company');
```

Answer (score 0):

As per laravel document , You can use other two methods which makes it more efficient to code .

- **FindOrFail**
- **FirstOrFail**

You can use the FirstOrFail method to get the first value easily in laravel .

For your code , it will be,

`$employee = Employee::firstOrFail();`

For more info , try this link

[Stackoverflow findorfail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33027047/what-is-the-difference-between-find-findorfail-first-firstorfail-get)

Answer (score 0):

You should add `with` before `find` like this

```
$employee = Employee::with('company')->find($id)->first();
// OR try simple way
$employee = Employee::with('company')->findOrFail($id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use :

```
  Employee::join('company','employee.id','=','company.employee_id')->where('employee.id','='$id')->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use **laravel Eloquent FindOrFail**.

For more see documentation [Retrieving Single Models / Aggregates](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#retrieving-single-models)