# why laravel's queries return nvarchar instead of int?

Tags: laravel, input, int

i have thoses lines of code :

```
 $idprat = Praticien::select('ID_Praticien')->where('NOM',$request->input('ID_Praticien'))->get();
        $mission->ID_Praticien = $idprat;
```

and i have this error message :

```
la valeur nvarchar '[{"ID_Praticien":1}]' en type de données int
```

why it's return me nvarchar on a int column on my database ?
i tried to make it correct like this :

```
$idprat = Praticien::select('ID_Praticien')->where('NOM',$request->input('ID_Praticien'))->get()->first();
```

and i tried with :

```
 $mission->ID_Praticien = (int)$idprat;
```

but doesnt work

i just selected ID_Praticien value not an array xD

thanks for help ;)

Comment: Show table schema

Comment: Can you add complete error? as $idprat will return collection not a single value, try to use pluck function. That may help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$idprat = Praticien::select('ID_Praticien')->where('NOM',$request->input('ID_Praticien'))->get();
        $mission->ID_Praticien = $idprat[0]->ID_Praticien;
```

or

```
$idprat = Praticien::select('ID_Praticien')->where('NOM',$request->input('ID_Praticien'))->first();
        $mission->ID_Praticien = $idprat->ID_Praticien;
```

Comment: thx everyone, it was this `$idprat[0]->ID_Praticien;` it is a bit Strange, this queries give an array no ?

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33027047/what-is-the-difference-between-find-findorfail-first-firstorfail-get , When occur this type of error better way is print the data and check for more information. as an example add this code and run the function after your query. then you can find the return values: dd($idprat);