# "Property [role] does not exist on this collection instance."

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a method that checks if a role is equal to 1 and then sends back some data. The method looks like so:

```
 if($user->role == 1) {
                $dmca = Dmca::get()->take(5);

                $data = [
                    'status' => 200,
                    'data' => $dmca
                ];

                return response($data);
            } else {
                $dmca = Dmca::where('client', $request->user_id)->get()->take(5);

                $data = [
                    'status' => 200,
                    'data' => $dmca
                ];

                return response($data);
            }
        }
```

On the dump and die of the $user instance, you can see the role is there and is set. But on return, I get the error

```
#attributes: array:11 [
        "id" => 1
        "name" => null
        "email" => "Grahammorbydev@gmail.com"
        "model_name" => "man"
        "subscribed" => 0
        "email_verified_at" => null
        "password" => "$2y$10$yy1Yj.GGez7efEdFdkjaf.RlQS17Zc7QYUANz3RvdE00fVm0f9AYq"
        "role" => 1
        "remember_token" => null
        "created_at" => "2020-07-05 17:54:38"
        "updated_at" => "2020-07-05 17:54:38"
      ]
```

Getting the following error when the axios returns

```
"Property [role] does not exist on this collection instance."
```

Comment: `$user` is an instance of  `Collection`. Can you show us how do you retrieve it ?

Comment: ```$user = User::where('id', $request->user_id)->get();```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message is shown

> "Property [role] does not exist on this collection instance."

It indicates that `$user` is an instance of `Collection`

You have to change

```
$user = User::where('id', $request->user_id)->get();
```

To this

```
$user = User::where('id', $request->user_id)->first();
```

- `get()` : returns a collection of models matching the query.
- `first()` : returns the first record found in the database. If no matching model exist, it returns null.

[more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33027047/what-is-the-difference-between-find-findorfail-first-firstorfail-get)