# Trying to get property of non-object when iterating results

Tags: php, laravel, object

I'm trying to show the data of offer's table by passing the id of the (index blade) page but this error shows when I open the (details blade):

> Trying to get property 'title' of non-object

The (details blade) page (the error shows in this page):

```
<div class="container row d-flex justify-content-center">
<div class="col-md-4 mb-4 float-left">

    @foreach($details as $detail)

    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body text-center">
            <h5 class="mt-0 mb-1 mb-2">{{$detail-> title}}</h5>
            <p class="grey-text mb-2" >{{$detail-> description}}</p>
            <p class="grey-text mb-2" id="price" >{{$detail-> price}}</p>
            <img
                src="https://www.91-img.com/pictures/133432-v4-xiaomi-mi-a3-mobile-phone-large-1.jpg?tr=q-60"
                class="my-3" alt="Angular logo">
            <br>
            <br>

            <a id="checkout" href="{{route('offers.checkout', $detail -> price )}}"
               role="button" class="btn  btn-success px-3 waves-effect waves-light"> شراء المنتج
            </a>
        </div>

    </div>
        @endforeach
```

The (index blade) page:

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">

        @if(isset($offers) && $offers -> count()> 0)
            @foreach($offers as $offer)
                <div class="col-md-4 mb-4">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body text-center">
                <h4>{{$offer -> title}}</h4>
                <p>{{$offer -> contnet}}</p>

                <img src="https://www.91-img.com/pictures/133432-v4-xiaomi-mi-a3-mobile-phone-large-1.jpg?tr=q-60">
                <br> <br>
                <a id="home-updates-angular" href="{{route('test_object.details', $offer -> id)}}" role="button" class="btn btn-success px-3 waves-effect waves-light">التفاصيل</a>
            </div>
        </div>
                </div>

            @endforeach
        @endisset


    </div>

</div>
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/test_object', 'testController@test_object')->name('test_object');
Route::get('/object/{id}', 'testController@object')->name('test_object.details');
```

Controller:

```
    public function test_object()
{
      $offers = Offer::get();
    return view('front.indext', compact('offers'));
}

public function object($id)
{
     $details = Offer::findOrFail($id);
    return view('front.detailst', compact('details'));
}
```

when I return:

```
return $details = Offer::findOrFail($id);
```

It shows this JSON:

```
{
"id": 1,
"title": "Samsung Galaxy S21",
"description": "Zoom X100",
"price": 20000
}
```

So, it supposed work in the (details blade) like that:

```
$details -> title
```

or any object

Comment: `{{$detail-> title}}` why do you have space between `->` and `title` here? Remove space there and check. like this `$details->title`

Comment: let me know if it doesn't work

Comment: [Amazingly, whitespace around the object operator works fine](https://3v4l.org/AsgZV).

Comment: This feels relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33027466/2943403

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#not-found-exceptions):

> The findOrFail .. methods will retrieve the first result of the query;

Note "*first result*" - not a Collection of results, but one result.  So `$details` here is a single model instance (if one is found):

```
$details = Offer::findOrFail($id);
```

You've verified this yourself by checking `$details`, you can see it is a single model, not a Collection:

```
{
"id": 1,
...
}
```

A Collection of one model would look something like this:

```
[{
"id": 1,
...
}]
```

But the view attempts to iterate over that single model:

```
@foreach($details as $detail)
```

Since `$details` is a single model instance, this will attempt to iterate over its properties, which will fail.

If you're only passing a single model to your view, just remove the `@foreach` iteration to display it.  It would also make sense to change your variable name in the controller to `$detail` since it is singular.

```
<div class="container row d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-4 mb-4 float-left">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body text-center">
                <h5 class="mt-0 mb-1 mb-2">{{ $detail->title }}</h5>
```

Side-note: There are many comments and answers here saying the spaces between your variable names and the object operator `->` are wrong and causing the error.  In fact spaces work fine (amazingly, at least to me), though as you can tell from the number of comments it is very unusual, and I expect considered poor coding style.

Comment: @foreach works if i make (details) like that:
$details[] 
now i understood why