# Laravel Eloquent getting data (with relationship) confusion

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am a bit confused on how to properly pull the data from Eloquent Models. I did read the documentation, but this is not mentioned anywhere or I missed it.

Let's assume we have two models, `Client` and `Country` (note: I only added relevant code, otherwise this question would be quite long):

Client:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Client;

use App\Models\BaseModel;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo;

/**
 * @property int    id
 * @property int    country_id
 */
class Client extends BaseModel
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        ...
        'country_id',
        ...
    ];

    /**
     * Return Country relationship
     *
     * @return BelongsTo
     */
    public function country(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Country::class);
    }
}
```

Country:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Country;

use App\Models\BaseModel;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany;

/**
 * @property int    id
 */
class Country extends BaseModel
{
    public function clients(): hasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Client::class);
    }
}
```

Nothing special, two normal Models. Now, when I try to pull the data I have a few issues:

- `dd(Country::findOrFail(32));` // CORRECT: returns selected country
- `dd(Country::findOrFail(32)->first());` // WRONG: returns first country in database, not the one with ID of 32, EXPECTED: single country object with selected country
- `dd(Country::findOrFail(32)->get());` // WRONG: returns all countries in database, EXPECTED: an array of objects with one country in it
- `dd(Country::with('clients')->findOrFail(32)->first());` // WRONG: returns first country in the database and not the one with ID of 32, relationship is also not correct, EXPECTED: object with selected country with valid relationship (clients) as array of objects
- `dd(Country::findOrFail(32)->clients());` // WRONG: returns HasMany relationship, no data, EXPECTED: an array of clients as objects
- `dd(Country::findOrFail(32)->clients()->get());` // CORRECT: returns valid data, array of clients as objects
- `dd(Country::findOrFail(32)->clients()->first());` // CORRECT: returns first client for selected country

So, why are all WRONG wrong ones? Am I interpreting the documentation wrongly? The most frustrating is `dd(Country::with('clients')->findOrFail(32)->first())` since now I have no means on how to filter based on selected country and then also provide a list of clients in that country. I thought that Eloquent is quite advanced, so I assume that I am doing something wrong and would appreciate some guidance.
Please note that in latest example I also tried reversing query as `dd(Country::findOrFail(32)->with('clients')->first())`, same result.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you are mixing up a few things here. For example, combining FindOrFail() with first() is double. Look here, that's a good explanation I found:

1. `find($id)` takes an id and returns a single model. If no matching
   model exist, it returns null.
2. `findOrFail($id)` takes an id and returns a single model. If no matching model exist, it throws an error1.
3. `first()` returns the first record found in the database. If no matching model exist, it returns null.
4. `firstOrFail()` returns the first record found in the database. If no matching model exist, it throws an error1.
5. `get()` returns a collection of models matching the query.
6. `pluck($column)` returns a collection of just the values in the given column. In previous versions of Laravel this method was called lists.
7. `toArray()` converts the model/collection into a simple PHP array.

*Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33027466/14807111*

Answer (score 0):

The method description for the Builder method `FindOrFail()` is:

> ```
>  * Find a model by its primary key or throw an exception.
> ```

In your usecase this method is calling the `find()`method and executing:

```
$this->whereKey($id)->first($columns);
```

This will return the first model and by default all of its columns. Therefore any other `first()` afterwards will introduce another query.

Your first three "Wrongs" are because  of execution order, the query executes the findOrFail first and afterwards it calls `first()` on the whole query again.

The fourth "WRONG" happens because your relationship returns a hasMany relationship, this is normal behaviour. You could either call `->get()` afterwards or call `->clients` without the `()` to receive the collection.

After all you are using the `first()` method wrong. You either use `find()`, `findOrFail()` or you use `->first()`.  But you should not use them together (there might be some edge cases where you have to, but genreally speaking, don't!).
Using `find()` or `findOrFail()` will already return the first() element that matched the `ID`.